# AWS Cognito pools, with Facebook and Required attribute as "Phone Number"

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, facebook-graph-api, amazon-cognito

I've created a AWS Cognito pool with Phone Number as required attribute and Facebook as one of federations. Since FB do not provide any Phone number during Oauth is there any workaround to map "any other FB attribute" to phone number so as user id is created (the attribute once in pool, can be changed later using api).

While I try to map it to available attributes on fb , I get this on url,

//redirect_uri#error_description=**attributes%20required:%20[birthdate,%20address,%20phone_number,%20email]**&state=STATE&error=invalid_request

Any workaround ? Help !

Comment: Could you please add the request which lead to the aboce error message?

Comment: in my pool, Required attributes are email, birthdate, phone_number, address. and the req https://my-zzzzzzzzzztifications.auth.ap-south-1.amazoncognito.com/login?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fknightlab.northwestern.edu&response_type=token&client_id=25i1oqhvjc9b77rjjmg64fvm1b&state=5O8pA4BA0OSFvqPJ9fWQ78nogQLID0ND&scope=profile%20email%20openid%20aws.cognito.signin.user.admin%20phone&userContextData=

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this ( rather correct this) by ensuring no parameters were used in AWScognito pool which are not provided by FB or google. Birthdate/Phone_numbers/Adress aren't provided by fb/google api

Comment: So, do you mean, FB/Google would never pass above these params? (Birthdate/Phone_numbers/Adresss)